# How can I fix my "Specified cast is not valid" error here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to get the id that is a `SMALLINT` using `OUTPUT` on an insert statement and using `DataContext.ExecuteQuery` (or whatever `DataContext` method would be more appropriate).

Attempt:

```
            string query = $@"
                DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE [Name] = '{name}'
                INSERT INTO MyTable ([Name], ...)
                OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
                VALUES ('{name}', ...)";
            short id = (short)context.ExecuteQuery<int>(query).Single();
```

and I get the error

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
       at Read_Int32(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

I tried using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and same thing happened.

Comment: Is the query valid? Because you are using `@`, your `query` string starts with a new line. You can remove it by starting the string on the same line: `string query = $@"DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE [Name] = '{name}' ..."`.

Comment: @Quantic that should not matter

Comment: Single will fail on an empty list -- try `FirstOrDefault()` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Hogan I want it to fail on an empty list

Comment: then you have achieved "Success!"

Answer (score 0):

remove the

OUTPUT INSERTED.ID

and add

; Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()

to the end, inside the quotes

ExecuteQuery expects a value to be returned in the result set which is different from an output variable.  The InvalidCastException comes from trying to convert the result set (which is null) to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
short id = context.ExecuteQuery<short>(query).Single();
```

That CAST exception is happening in the code when it's expecting SQL Server to return an Int32 and getting an Int16.